# MOSS 2007 - Maximum number of views for one list?

Tags: sharepoint, list, view, scalability, max

Is there a maximum number of views you can create for a list in SharePoint? I mean views like the ones which are listed in the top right corner o the `AllItems.aspx` page:

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dd365137.image009%28en-us%29.jpg))</sub>

Are there performance issues which arise when you add a lot of views to one list, like 50-100?

Comment: What are you doing that you need 50-100 views? If you're doing something like filtering on a value you may be better using filter web parts and web part connections.

Comment: @Ryan - It's for alerts; my users want to be able to filter which items in a discussion will alert them based on 'category' and I'm assessing whether the OOTB views can be used for this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is limit of 50 views per list, though no citations in any of the pages which suggest this.

- http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31692572/limit-on--of-views-in-se.aspx
- http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--general-question-answers-discussion/maximum-number-of-veiws-available-for-selection-in-listview-webpart-14097.shtml
- http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--setup-upgrade-administration-operation/limit-to-the-number-of-views-that-can-be-seen-7934.shtml
- http://wssv3faq.mindsharp.com/Lists/v3%20WSS%20FAQ/DispForm.aspx?ID=1125&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fwssv3faq.mindsharp.com%2FLists%2Fv3%2520WSS%2520FAQ%2FIII%2520Administration.aspx