# Customise the list of views on a document library

Tags: sharepoint, view

Is it possible to customise the list of views on a document library depending which webpages you are on? I planning to configure about 500 views on a large document library, but its impossible to navigate between 500 view...

Comment: Why in the world do you need 500 views?

Answer (score 1):

It is [unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293299/moss-2007-maximum-number-of-views-for-one-list) how [many views](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/maximum-number-views-imported-content-53241.aspx) a list can have. I'm not sure I'd add 500 views to a list, even if I could.

However, web parts can have custom views built into them. For example, the following is a trimmed down version of a web part that I used for a current project:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server"
    Title="Large Document Library"
    ListUrl="LargeDocumentLibrary"
    ChromeType="TitleOnly"
    >
    <XmlDefinition>
       <View MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Level="1">
           <Query>
                <Where>
                    <!-- Enter conditions here -->
                </Where>
            </Query>
           <ViewFields>
               <!-- Enter FieldRef elements here -->
           </ViewFields>
           <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
       </View>
    </XmlDefinition>
    <parameterbindings>
       <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
       <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
       <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
       <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
       <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
       <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
       <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
       <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
       <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
       <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" DefaultValue="" />
       <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
       <ParameterBinding Name="MoreAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,moreItemsParen)" />
    </parameterbindings>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

Comment: Thank you!

I have sent it to my developer.